# Why do Facebook API calls reset the connection only in my development environment?

Tags: facebook, api

Our application calls Facebook API methods in a couple of different places. It's in Ruby and uses HTTParty. These calls fail on my own machine with "Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect", after a long timeout, both in tests and in my development instance of the application. They succeed on other developers' machines, and in production and in production-like environments. Code and configuration are in version control so I'm confident that they're the same in environments where this works and and on my machine. These calls succeeded on my machine until a few days ago. I would like them to succeed on my machine once again!

A couple of the calls that fail:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=(an access token just retrieved from Facebook's auth dialog)
GET https://graph.facebook.com/(application ID)/accounts/test-users?access_token=(application ID)%7C(application secret)
```

These calls also fail in the same way when I attempt to GET them with curl.

Alhough this phenomenon is recent I can't think of anything that changed on my machine recently before this phenomenon began. I can't even think of a good place to start looking. The only thing I can think of is that I've been running tests frequently lately, so perhaps Facebook thinks I'm an evil robot. I can't think of how Facebook could tell it's me, however, and I've seen this problem when the machine was behind two different IP addresses.

Any suggestions, anyone?

For what it's worth the machine is Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: Are you able to manually reach graph.facebook.com? Are your DNS lookups failing? Is your machine's CURL config rejecting the request because of a certificate check on the HTTPS connection?
(i.e do HTTP URLS work OK?)

Comment: Yes, I can reach graph.facebook.com in a browser. DNS is fine. The same calls with HTTP instead of HTTPS fail immediately and tell me that they require HTTPS. It might be certificates, though. The error above is what I see in the browser when a call from my dev instance of my app fails. curl fails with "curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443". wget fails with "ERROR: The certificate of `graph.facebook.com' is not trusted." These errors don't clearly point to my end but I'll compare my certificates to those of a machine that doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in MacPorts OpenSSL 1.1, which I installed recently along with a pile of other upgrades. Reported here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33715 The solution is to 'port activate' the previous, working version.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said above it's almost certainly your (machine/curl) config rejecting Facebook's SSL cert.
It could be that your system doesn't have the right root certificates or there's some proxy (e.g. Charles) in place which is mangling the certificate

As a hacky solution, you could use `--no-check-certificate` if using curl on command line, or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to false for PHP - I really don't recommend doing that in a production environment though

Also possibly relevant: you could be missing some intermediate certificates from Digicert: See https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm for the signatures